# Minikube on VM: this computer doesn't have vt-x/amd-v enabled

Tags: virtual-machine, minikube

I'm trying to run minikube inside virtualbox, and got this error:

```
this computer doesn't have vt-x/amd-v enabled
```

Even i have this setting enabled on my virtual machine.
I tried aslo drivers KVM, KVM2 - they also not starting due to "virtualisation is not enabled".

Although virtualbox app is running correctly on this machine, and starts it's machines

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need support for nested virtualization, and this has not yet been implemented in VirtualBox.

See this VirtualBox ticket:
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032

You may have more luck with VMWare, as indicated in the comments. I'll update this later if I find something that works (I need to use Minikube inside a VM also).

UPDATE: I confirm that this works just fine in VMWare Workstation 14.